# Does running a IMessageService processes in ASP.NET ensure that it does not recycle the AppPool?

Tags: iis-7.5, servicestack

I haven't had the opportunity to test this on my own yet so I thought I'd reach out and see if anyone has had experience with it.

So if I have a ServerStack ASP.NET hosted service running in IIS, and use the RedisMqServer or RabbitMqServer, the background worker threads will prevent the AppPool from recycling under normal circumstances?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Background threads in ASP.NET does not prevent an ASP.NET AppDomain from recycling. You can use the [IIS7.5/ASP.NET 4.0 Auto-Start Feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanket/archive/2012/01/30/auto-start-your-asp-net-apps.aspx) to automatically boot up ASP.NET applications.